# How can I map over numpy dataset?

Tags: python, numpy

I am working with [Keras](https://github.com/fchollet/keras) and the provided MNIST data set. I believe the dataset is a numpy array. I have reshaped it as follows:

```
X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 1, 28, 28)
X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], 1, 28, 28)
```

This gives a `(60000, 1, 28, 28)` numpy array. This can be read as there are 60000 28 x 28 images. I want to extract every single 28 x 28 image and apply some sort of function `f` to it. I have tried the following:

```
f = lambda a, _: print a.shape
np.apply_over_axes(f, data, [2,3])
```

But I am unsure exactly the second `axis` parameter comes into play though...

I have also tried:

```
f = lambda a: print a.shape
np.apply_along_axis(f, 0, data)
```

But the shape is always `(60000,)` instead of what I would expect `(1, 28, 28)`. How do I get each subimage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no performance gained by using `np.apply_along_axis`, `np.vectorize`, etc. Just use a loop:

```
import numpy as np

s = (4,1,28,28)
a = np.zeros(s)
for img in a[:,0]:
    print(img.shape)

# (28, 28)
# (28, 28)
# (28, 28)
# (28, 28)
```

Comment: Ahh ok. This notation makes more sense! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This `lambda` doesn't make sense:

```
lambda a, _: print a.shape
```

it's equivalent to

```
def foo(a, x):
   return print a.shape
```

`print a.shape` prints something, and returns nothing, maybe even an error.

`lambda a,x: a.shape` is better, returning the shape of `a`, and ignoring the `x` argument.

If the size `1` dimension is in the way, why not just omit it?

```
X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 28, 28)
```

or remove it

```
X_train[:,0,...]
np.squeeze(X_train)
```

But what's the point of the apply_over?  Just to find the shape of a set of submatrices?

```
In [304]: X = np.ones((6,1,2,3))
In [305]: [x.shape for x in X]
Out[305]: [(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3)]
```

or

```
[x.shape for x in X[:,0]]
```

to remove the 2nd dimension, getting just the shape of the last 2.

This `apply_along_axis`, iterates on the last 3 dim, passing a 1d array to the lambda.  So in effect it is returning `X[:,0,i,j].shape`.

```
In [308]: np.apply_along_axis(lambda a: a.shape, 0, X)
Out[308]: 
array([[[[6, 6, 6],
         [6, 6, 6]]]])
```

Generally iterations like this aren't needed.  And when used, are slow compared to 'full-array' ones.

Comment: `return print expr` returns `None`. All I'm trying to test for is dimension, so the `lambda` is basically useless. As for the `1` dimension the tutorial I followed said this is needed for the neural networks: https://elitedatascience.com/keras-tutorial-deep-learning-in-python
`_` by convention is what is used to ignore variables.

Comment: I am trying to give a minimal verifiable example. As it stands the apply_over call is just to demonstrate my issue. Ultimately, I want to apply a function over each of the 60000 images. But currently, `f` doesn't print a `(1, 28, 28)` matrix, it prints `(60000,)` matrix. But I want to apply a function to each `(1, 28, 28)` matrix.

Comment: Then just loop on the 1st dimension: `[f(x) for x in X]`.

Comment: But what are the 2 variables that get passed to your function in the `apply_over` with [2,3]` case?

Comment: I thought those were axis, so I would pass `[2, 3]` to get the 28 x 28 image, but it appears that I had pretty big misunderstanding with how numpy arrays work...

Comment: It's more a misunderstanding of how these 2 `apply` functions work.  They are intended to make certain kinds of iteration easier, but often they confuse more than help.  I know arrays well, but still have to experiment when people ask questions about these `apply` functions.